# Jacoco coverage doesn't work with latest android plugin

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

Im getting this below error after updating the gradle android plugin.

Execution failed for task ':App:jacocoTestReport'.

> Unable to read execution data file app/build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec

jacoco version = "0.7.6.201602180812"

android plugin version:  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

Is there any problem with the latest plugin?